# Nixos: how to install deps in jupyter notebook?

Tags: nixos

I'm trying to install Jupyter notebook on NixOs, but I can't find how to install numpy, and other libraries into jupyter. For now I added in my `configuration.nix` something like:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:
let
  python3-with-my-packages =
    pkgs.python3.withPackages (python-packages: with python-packages; [
      numpy
  ]);
in
{
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    python3-with-my-packages
    jupyter
  ];
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A small `shell.nix` file for a Jupyter Notebook could look like the following.

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

(pkgs.python3.withPackages (ps: with ps; [
    ipykernel jupyterlab
    matplotlib numpy pandas seaborn
    networkx
  ])).env
```

To start, copy a modified version of the `shell.nix` file to your project directory and run `nix-shell --run "jupyter lab"`.

Comment: Thanks. This is close to the solution with `notebook`, except that `notebook` is replaced with `jupyterlab`. Any idea if I could make this work directly with the raw `jupyter` meta-package?

Comment: I typed `nix-shell shell.nix  --run "jupyter lab"` and I did not try without `shell.nix`. The file of this folder are accessible, in the jupyter interface, this is nice !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not claiming this is the best solution, but it seems that the `jupyter` package is not the one we need, but instead we just want to add the python package `notebook` to the list of deps:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:
let
  python3-with-my-packages =
    pkgs.python3.withPackages (python-packages: with python-packages; [
      numpy
      notebook
  ]);
in
{
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    python3-with-my-packages
  ];
  [...]
}
```

Let me know if it's not the way to go and if there is a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at the topic [Jupyter notebook with batteries](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/jupyter-notebook-with-batteries/1839) in NixOS Discourse for some discussion on the Nixy dependency management for Jupyter Notebook.

If you want something compatible with non-Nix environment, I just managed to find a way to use Poetry inside NixOS with the help of `mkPoetryEnv` and `buildFHSUserEnv`:

Just place two files in the top-level directory of the Poetry project:

#### `poetry-env.nix`

```
{pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
let
  lib = pkgs.lib;
  poetry2nix = pkgs.poetry2nix;
  python37 = pkgs.python37;
in
  poetry2nix.mkPoetryEnv {
    python = python37;
    pyproject = ./pyproject.toml;
    poetrylock = ./poetry.lock;
  }
```

#### `poetry-env-fhs.nix`

```
{
  pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {},
  # This allows us to provide a command to run via `--argstr run COMMAND`.
  run ? "bash"
}:
let
  poetry-env = import ./poetry-env.nix { };
in
  with pkgs; (buildFHSUserEnv {
    name = "poetry-env-fhs";
    targetPkgs = pkgs: with pkgs; [
      # curl
      # git
      gcc
      gnumake
      python37Packages.poetry
      pandoc # for pdf conversion
      texlive.combined.scheme-full # for pdf conversion
      which # a convenient tool in vertualized environments
    ] ++ [
      poetry-env
    ];
    runScript = "${run}";
    profile = ''
      # export SSL_CERT_FILE=${cacert}/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
      # export GIT_SSL_CAINFO="$SSL_CERT_FILE"
      # export LANG=C.UTF-8
    '';
  }).env
```

Since it takes quite a while for mkPoetryEnv to build a package, you may want to
`nix-build ./poetry-env.nix` to keep the build result from being GC-ed.

[Jupyter notebook dependency management with Poetry](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/jupyter-notebook-dependency-management-with-poetry/8129)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. When posting an answer, try posting the entire solution in to your post. Don't redirect to other websites if not necessary.

Comment: @Rayleigh Thanks for telling me that.

Answer (score 0):

There a great write up here of using Juypter with Nixos.

https://www.tweag.io/blog/2019-02-28-jupyter-with/